# split string into list by regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need a regex, which split input string to list with next rules:
1) By dot;
2) Do not split expression if it is in quotes.
Examples:

```
'a.b.c' -> ['a', 'b', 'c'];
'a."b.c".d' -> ['a', 'b.c', 'd'];
'a.'b.c'.d' -> ['a', 'b.c', 'd'];
'a.'b c'.d' -> ['a', 'b c', 'd'];
```

Comment: Why is regex a requirement? Can you also share your existing attempt? In particular, provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: use csv.reader (with StringIO) and set the delimiter with the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module with the following expression:

```
(["']).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.
```

This captures quotes, match them up to the next quote and let the matched part fail. The alternation is the dot.

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

data = """
a.b.c
a."b.c".d
a.'b.c'.d
a.'b c'.d
"""

rx = re.compile(r"""(["']).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.""")

for line in data.split("\n"):
    if line:
        parts = [part.strip("'").strip('"') for part in rx.split(line) if part]
        print(parts)
```

Which yields

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b.c', 'd']
['a', 'b.c', 'd']
['a', 'b c', 'd']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/G3IdCe/1).

---

If you want to stick with the `re` module, you could *replace* the dot in question before and split by the replacement afterwards.

```
import re

data = """
a.b.c
a."b.c".d
a.'b.c'.d
a.'b c'.d
"""

rx = re.compile(r"""(["']).*?\1|(?P<dot>\.)""")
needle = "SUPERMAN"

def replacer(match):
    if match.group('dot') is not None:
        return needle
    else:
        return match.group(0)

for line in data.split("\n"):
    if line:
        line = rx.sub(replacer, line)
        parts = [part.strip("'").strip('"') for part in line.split(needle) if part]
        print(parts)
```

This yields the exact same output as above. Please note that both approaches won't work for escaped quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some extra efforts here how can you do.

First split with '.' and then do some logically work on it.

```
string_data = 'a."b.c".d'
data = string_data.split('.')

list = []
value = None
for i in range(0,len(data)):    
    if value:
        value = None
    else:
        if '"' in data[i]:
            value = data[i]
            value = value + '.' + data[i+1]
        if value:
            list.append(value)
        else:
            list.append(data[i])
print(list)
```

It will give you output same as in your qus.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could try using an or `|` with a positive lookbehind `(?<=` and a positive lookahead `(?=` for the single and double quotes

[`(?<=").*?(?=")|(?<=').*?(?=')|[a-z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/WXQ4E7/1)

```
regex = r"(?<=\").*?(?=\")|(?<=').*?(?=')|[a-z]+"
line = "a.\"b.t\".qq.d.d.'d'.'d.g.r'.d.d"
print(re.findall(regex, line))
```

> ['a', 'b.t', 'qq', 'd', 'd', 'd', '.', 'd.g.r', 'd', 'd']

[Test output python](http://rextester.com/GWDIBJ97843)

Answer (score -1):

here is a [regex for you](https://regex101.com/r/o8r92H/3):

```
\.?([^\"\'\.]+)|\"(.+)\"|\'(.+)\'\.?
```

implementation:

```
import re
regex = re.compile( r"""\.?([^\"\'\.]+)|\"(.+)\"|\'(.+)\'\.?""")

def str2list(string):
    b = regex.findall(string)
    l = []
    for i in list(b):
        for j in list(i):
            if j:
                l.append(j)
    return l

str2list('a.b.c')
str2list('a."b.c".d')
str2list("a.'b.c'.d")
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b.c', 'd']
['a', 'b.c', 'd']
```

Comment: Okay. Its a wrong regex. When you try to parse string like
    `"a.\"b.t\".qq"`
List looks like 
`['a', 'b.t', 'q', 'q']`

Comment: @creedqq pass it as `r"""a."b.t".qq"""` or `"""a.\"b.t\".qq"""` or `'a.\"b.t\".qq'`

Comment: It isn't natural form. When you want to pass a string into the method, you shouldn't think about it.
And I can't pass string like `'a.first.test_one'`, all splitted by char

Comment: @creedqq try again - should be fixed now